# Listener for CheckBox in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, itemlistener

I am adding a listener to the JCheckBox present in the JTable. I am having a issue with following code,

```
public class CheckBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor implements ItemListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JCheckBox checkBox;

private int row;
private int column;

public CheckBoxEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    this.checkBox = checkBox;
    this.checkBox.addItemListener(this);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
    checkBox.setSelected((Boolean) value);
    return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    this.fireEditingStopped();
    System.out.println("Item Changed " + row + " value is: " + checkBox.isSelected());
}

}
```

and in I am using above class as,

```
tableA.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellEditor(new CheckBoxEditor(new JCheckBox()));
```

When ever I click on the check boxes in the column I am reaching the  itemStateChanged method. The problem is, on selection of a check box my itemStateChanged method is calling twice and some times only once.

**This is the sample output.** (I had 5 rows. And when I am making true all the check boxes I am getting this double syso printings.)

```
Item Changed 0 value is: true

Item Changed 1 value is: false

Item Changed 1 value is: true

Item Changed 2 value is: false

Item Changed 2 value is: true

Item Changed 3 value is: false

Item Changed 3 value is: true

Item Changed 4 value is: false

Item Changed 4 value is: true
```

Comment: I would think that you would use a TableModelListener added to the JTable's model, not something added to a row editor component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion .. let me try this..

Comment: @Che ItemListener always firing twice, have to determine if SELECTED or DESELECTED, then sugestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your listener is triggered when you click on the checkboxes, but also when the selected state is changed trough the API.

And since the editor always reuses the same checkbox it is constantly updating the selected value.

Main question is ... why would you need to attach a listener to it ?

Comment: I need to know when the check boxes are selected .. basing on this I need to call the methods that are associated with this change. If this is wrong way .. can you tell me something better than this.

Comment: @Che As suggested by Hovercraft, you need to listen to changes in the model, not in the editor

Comment: @Che if you want to know when the checkbox is selected, consider using `ActionListener` rather than `ItemListener`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet awesome .. it worked .. but ver curious to know  what is the difference in ItemChnaged and ActionListener for JTable